# Does any Linux X terminal update line-wrapping on resize?

Tags: linux, terminal, x-windows

The Mac OS X Terminal will rewrap lines when the window is resized. Is this functionality available in any terminal emulator for Linux?

I'd prefer to do this with terminals like `gnome-terminal` that are included in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04's gnome-terminal seems to support line-wrapping when the window is resized now.

Comment: [Dynamic line wrapping in the GNOME Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/54995/253474) https://coderwall.com/p/fzprda/getting-text-to-reflow-on-window-resize-in-gnome-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html)-256color version 9.07-3 (as provided by arch Linux) is confirmed to do this. The version of urxvt on my debian stable system does not. It should be easy enough to figure out how the ubuntu version behaves.

Other than that, the terminals I know of that will re-wrap are [9term](http://www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~matty/9term/), [M-x shell](http://jamesthornton.com/emacs/node/emacs_444.html#SEC444) in emacs, and a weird old app called [xmlterm](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/06/07/xmlterm/index.html), which is a terminal emulator made using mozilla xul. Sadly what these have in common is that they do not support curses terminal control (ie. no running vi or nano or top or emacs or nethack etc. in these terminals). And other than emacs M-x shell they appear to not be actively developed (or even all that easy to find any more).

Comment: rxvt-unicode v9.06 in Ubuntu 9.10 does this.
v9.07 in Fedora 12 same as Arch (does).

Very cool to know this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer that rxvt-unicode-256color works, however on my system it re-wraps only when enlarging the window. If you shrink the window, text is lost, and then when you re-enlarge it, you don't get it back.

Comment: rxvt-unicode-256color on my Fedora 17 system rewraps correctly both when shrinking and enlarging the window. (Package I'm using is rxvt-unicode-256color-9.15-1.fc17.)

Answer (score 6):

GNU screen does this, and supports curses properly.  Run it in whatever terminal emulator you want:  http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

I would be surprised if tmux didn't automatically rewrap lines, too.  tmux also supports curses; e.g., you can run vi in screen or tmux with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

gnome-terminal supports this from version 3.11 on (since late 2013):

From the [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTU0MDE) website:

> For long lines of text within the GNOME Terminal, when expanding the window's screen the word-wrapping will now automatically update. This is a change that should be found in GNOME 3.12 but there's still some developers evaluating its design, etc. The updated Terminal has already landed in Fedora (21) Rawhide for those interested.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidPostill: In this case, it looks like the link is just a citation to support the answer.

Answer (score 1):

VTE (the engine of Gnome-terminal) supports this, starting with version 0.35.